# Default attribute route does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller and want to define default route on it, like as follow:

```
public class SignInController : Controller
{
    [Route("", Name = "Default")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

on the `RoutingConfig` I comment out `MapRoute`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  /*routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new {controller = "SignIn", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );*/
}
```

When I start to server, I've got:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
>   the contents of this directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You doing attribute routing but are missing the configuration...

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    /*routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         new {controller = "SignIn", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
      );*/
}
```

...which will map the attribute-defined routes for the application.

Also if you are going to be using attribute routing you may want to set a route prefix for your controller.

```
[RoutePrefix("SignIn")]
public class SignInController : Controller
{
    //eg: GET signin/
    [Route("", Name = "Default")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

If you want the `SignInController.Index` to map to your root then set the `RoutePrefix` to  `""` (empty string)

Take a look at [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)